# natbib + BibTeX: suppress url if doi is available

Tags: bibtex, natbib, conditionals, urls, doi

I am using `natbib` (+ BibTeX). Some entries in my bibliography file (`.bib`) have the field `doi`, some have `url` and some have both.
I would like to edit the bibliography style file (`.bst`) so that, if `doi` is available, `url` is suppressed.

At the moment, the `.bst` file has the functions:

```
FUNCTION {format.doi}
{ doi empty$
    { "" }
    {
      new.block
      "\doi{" doi * "}" *
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.url}
{
  url
  duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "\urlprefix\url{" swap$ * "}" * }
  if$
}
```

[I was looking for a solution to this problem and found some similar questions and answers. However, they didn't address this specific case. After searching and trying, I could solve it. I present the solution as a reply for my own question to document it.]

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve it by testing if `doi` is empty inside the function `format.url`. Replace your `format.url` by the following:

```
FUNCTION {format.url}
{
  doi empty$
    {    
      url
      duplicate$ empty$
        { pop$ "" }
        { "\urlprefix\url{" swap$ * "}" * }
      if$
    }
    { "" }
  if$
}
```

Comment: Would you mind editing the answer and pointing to the `.bst` file? Where is it usually? Can it be a custom add-on file, integrated while compiling the `.tex` and `.bib` source files?

Comment: @NikosAlexandris, I don't mind, but I don't think this edition is needed in order to answer the question. The question is about a achieving a specific goal, not about how to use a .bst file.

Comment: It does not work for me. The error message reads: `[9] (somefilename.bbl [10]
! Undefined control sequence.
l.122   \urlprefix
                  \url{http://www.globtemperature.info/}.
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.` Any hints?